# How is a Forth value different from a variable?

Tags: forth

Reading the Gforth manual, a value can be changed using the word `TO`, so how is it different than a variable?

https://gforth.org/manual/Values.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VALUE` takes an initial value, and the created word puts the value directly on the stack like `CONSTANT`. The value can still be changed using `TO`. Word definitions in many Forths using `VALUE`'s will be smaller, because they just need to reference the created word and not `!`.

```
5 VALUE TERRYS
TERRYS . 5 ok
```

`VARIABLE` just reserves space for the value, uninitialised, and the created word puts the address of the variable on the stack instead.

```
VARIABLE TERRYS
5 TERRYS !
TERRYS @ . 5 ok
```

`VARIABLE` is useful when you want to take the address of the variable, and `VALUE` is useful when you don't need to.

If you want to initialise the variable, and be able to take the address, it is actually easier to just use `CREATE` and `,`, like so:

```
CREATE TERRYS 5 ,
TERRYS @ . 5 ok
```

Answer (score 3):

if you define a word as `5 value A`

when you type `A`

you get 5 put on the stack

when you type `variable A`

when you type `A`

you get an address put on the stack

to get the value inside, you use `@`

to write to it, you use `!`

`value` creates a word that puts a value on the stack

`variable` creates a word that puts an address on the stack